# "bag" vs "package"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, american-english

In American English, would you say that chips, cookies, and candies are usually packed in **bags** or would you say they are packed in **packages**? I can't see much difference between a plastic bag and a rather big loose plastic package as their definitions seem to overlap to an indefinite extent. Would you please help me distinguish those concepts ("bag" and "package") when it comes to food packaging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd call this a *package* of cookies:

[image: package]

I'd call this a *bag* of chips:

[image: bag]

I'd call this a *box* of cereal:

[image: box]

The *box* is made of cardboard on all sides. The *bag* has no firm sides, and no inner packaging; it's much like a sealed pouch. A *package* is often made using a material similar to the bag, but the inner plastic tray makes it a *package*.

NOTE: This is only for packaged foods. There are other kinds of bags:

[image: bags]

and this is a package made from a box:

[image: a package while it's being shipped that becomes a box once it's emptied]

Interestingly enough, after you open that *package*, it becomes an *empty box*.

Comment: This is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 7):

**“Bag”** is definitely the word of choice for packaging that is loose, allowing for movement of the contents.

**“Package”** would be understood, but is generally reserved for rigid packaging (even if the outside consists of sealed plastic). A point of possible confusion is that many people use “package” when referring to something that has been (and is currently) packed for shipping (e.g. cardboard boxes).

**“Box”** does not appear on your list, but, in my mind, is the word in general use for rigid containers with rectangular sides (usually made from thin cardboard and containing a sealed bag which holds the items).

This probably goes without saying, but the convention is always to refer to the outermost container.

Answer (score 0):

A *bag* is a specific type of container, made from a loose material, such as plastic or cloth, although there are also paper *bags*.

A *package*, generally speaking, refers to the entire packing container and its contents.  This could be contained within a bag, a box, or some custom wrapping of sorts.